# pkill process containing special characters

Tags: shell, kill

trying to run pkill on file with "+" in the name

```
pkill -SIGTERM -f "auth+live+ec575698789349860987088t897906769878968970"
```

if i take out this part "auth+live+" I am successful

I've tried putting it in quotes , without , single and double as well, is there any way to get this to work

Comment: i really like to know how this questions is not about programming i'm writing a a bash script ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excerpts from the `pkill` manual:

```
SYNOPSIS

    pkill [options] pattern

OPERANDS

    pattern
        Specifies an Extended Regular Expression for matching against the
        process names or command lines.
```

So pkill interpretes '+' in your argument as a special pattern character. Use
backslash to escape it. If you're using doublequotes for quoting or don't quote at all, escape backslashes so Bash doesn't interpret them. Like this:

```
pkill -SIGTERM -f "auth\\+live\\+ec575698789349860987088t897906769878968970"
```

Comment: is there some way in bash to do the escaping as this will be contained within a a larger script

Comment: @mcgrailm I'm not sure what is the problem in doing escaping in a script. Could you please elaborate and/or post the code in an addition to your question and I'll add the answer to my answer?

Comment: @mcgrailm If you want to escape the pattern automatically, you can do something like this: `escaped_pattern=$(echo -n "$pattern" | sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/\\&/g')`. I'd use backticks instead of `$()` but that's reserved for stackoverflow formatting. Then you can invoke pkill with it: `pkill -SIGTERM -f "$escaped_pattern"`

Comment: thank you :) I ended up using fn=${fn//+/\\+} to use simple string replace which is fine because they will never have any other characters :)